# Document library in .NET

Tags: .net, iis, document

I'm looking for document library. Which allow users to tag files in certain categories but let files saved on PCs in network. This database let users search on intranet website. And use IIS as Web server and MSSQL as db server.

Any Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One answer to this question could be Microsoft Sharepoint but that's a ton of **bloat** that you may not need. However, this is Microsoft's "canonical" solution to the problem you describe above.

Answer (score 0):

you might search for a document management solution that is web based, if you are looking for a commercial product SharePoint would work and Win2k3 comes with it. If you Need MOSS then you will need to purchase that.

You can also try this [http://www.knowledgetree.com/](http://wwww.knowledgetree.com)